# Unable to set Left Alignment for button title in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

It's very easy to Left-Align CCLabelTTF, but CCButton seems to have a problem with alignments.

setting `button.horizontalpadding = CCTextAlignmentLeft;` has no affect on button alignment.
I have attempted to modify properties `preferredSize` and `contentSize` in order to create boxes for alignment without success.

Comment: Can't you just get the CCLabelTTF of the button and align that? You can access it with the `button.label` property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont this there is a CCButton class in cocos2d. I assume you are talking about CCMenuItelLabel. Try this way:

```
        CGPoint rightAlligned = ccp(1.0f, 0.5f);
        CGPoint leftAlligned = ccp(0.0f, 0.5f);


   button.label.anchorPoint = leftAligned; //For left text align
   button.label.anchorPoint = rightAligned; //For right text align
```

Comment: Cocos2d V3 has CCButton, I believe CCMenuItemLabel is gone now.

Comment: I have not tried v3 yet. May be you are right. But the above answer is still valid. I assumed CCMenuItelLabel might be there. But button.label.anchorpoint= left alignment should still work if the class is of ccbutton in v3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "Anchor Point" not "Aliment property" here is sample that can help you:

```
CCLabel _label= new CCLabel("sample text here!", "Fonts/font.otf", 60, CCTextAlignment.Left);
_label.AnchorPoint = new CCPoint(0.0f, 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this yet, but I would try

```
[button.label setHorizontalAlignment:CCTextAlignmentLeft];
```